# What is the syntax for ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana

Trying to figure out Kibana's ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS syntax, but I receive either:

```
kib01     |  FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts]: types that failed validation:
kib01     | - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.0]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].
kib01     | - [config validation of [elasticsearch].hosts.1]: could not parse array value from json input
```

from Kibana itself or:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.kibana.environment.ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS contains ["http://es01:9200", "http://es02:9200", "http://es03:9200", "http://es04:9200"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null
```

from Docker compose.

My latest iteration is:

```
environment:
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://es01:9200", "http://es02:9200", "http://es03:9200", "http://es04:9200"]
```

I have also tried:

```
environment:
  - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200", "http://es02:9200", "http://es03:9200", "http://es04:9200"]'
```

I tried turning that into a list:

```
environment:
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:
    - "<host1>"
    - "<host2>"
```

I tried removing quotes in various places in the above variation and various combinations on the list.

I also tried a combination from the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html) using both `:` and `=`

with `ELASTICSEARCH_HOST = http://es01:9200, http://es02:9200...`

All have been rejected. Does anyone know the magic syntax to get this to work?

### Updated List of failures:

```
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: ['http://es01:9200','http://es02:9200','http://es03:9200','http://es04:9200']
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="['http://es01:9200','http://es02:9200','http://es03:9200','http://es04:9200']"
  - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=['http://es01:9200','http://es02:9200','http://es03:9200','http://es04:9200']
  - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200","http://es04:9200"]"
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:
    - "<host1>"
    - "<host2>"
```

Comment: Please make sure the environment variable you're using has the plural `S` at the end or not. Then, what about `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="['http://es01:9200','http://es02:9200','http://es03:9200','http://es04:9200']"`? Also, what is the error message for the `I have also tried:` part?

Comment: What is your version of Kibana? A fix was introduce in kibana 6.6.1

Comment: @AliTou I get: `The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.kibana.environment.ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS contains ["http://es01:9200", "http://es02:9200", "http://es03:9200", "http://es04:9200"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null`

Comment: @jmaitrehenry 7.7

Comment: It thinks you're passing a list as the value. I think using double quotes around and single quotes inside must work. Any results with the suggested one?

Comment: @AliTou - I tried it. I get: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.kibana.environment contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or an array` and that was using `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="['http://es01:9200','http://es02:9200','http://es03:9200','http://es04:9200']"`

Comment: As the error mentions, you must either define your `environment` section as a key-value map (`KEY: VALUE`) or an array (`- KEY=VALUE`). I can't write multi-line here, but please fix this according to how you defined `environment` section. (all of your attempts to write this section was incorrect)

Comment: @AliTou I don't understand what you mean. The key here is ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS. Are you saying define it multiple times in a list? It sounds like you have an answer - do you want to just post it as an answer? That might be easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some things to note to solve your problem:

- In docker-compose, your environment variables must be written as an object, or an array:

```yaml
# A native yaml approach to define key-value objects
environment:  
  KEY1: VAL1
  KEY2: VAL2
# OR
# Some special way for compose yaml parser
# that can split key and value from a "KEY=VAL" string
environment:  
  - KEY1=VAL1
  - KEY2=VAL2
```

- The value of an environment variable must be a string (the above example), a number, or null (empty value). Note that `[foo, bar]` is parsed as a list in the first format (and if you want it to be parsed as a string, you need to wrap it inside quotation marks), but the second format parses it as a string.
- In [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-setting-multiple-elasticsearch-hosts-over-marathon-template/202662/2) forum question, there is an example to how pass multiple elasticsearch hosts as an environment variable (`ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`).

So this must be a valid example that docker-compose and Kibana can both understand:

```yaml
environment:
  ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200","http://es04:9200"]'
# OR
environment:
  - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200","http://es04:9200"]
```

Comment: The first one worked. At first I thought it didn't - I realized I hadn't used a colon! Thank you so much!